# WP_Query by just the id?

Tags: wp-query

In the codex for `WP_Query` I see you can query by `page_id=7` for pages or by `p=7` for posts. Is there a way to get a *post of any post type* by ID? Like `id=7` that will get it no matter if it's a page, post or custom post type?

I can only get `WP_Query` with `p=7` to work if I add `&post_type=customposttype`. Is there a way to get it from the ID regardless of the post type?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

`any` should retrieve any type:

```
$args = array(
  'p'         => 42, // ID of a page, post, or custom type
  'post_type' => 'any'
);
$my_posts = new WP_Query($args);
```

Note the description of `any` in the documentation:

> 'any' - retrieves any type except revisions and types with 'exclude_from_search' set to true.

For more information, have a look at the documentation of [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Type_Parameters).

Comment: for specifics or multiple post try `$query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'any', 'post__in' => array( 2, 5, 12, 14, 20 ) ) );` you can use postTypes = page, post, any ;