# Display title of custom post type dynamically

Tags: custom-post-types, get-the-title

I've registered my custom post type in `functions.php` like so:

```
function whatwedo_custom_post_type()
{
    register_post_type('whatwedo',
                       array(
                           'labels'      => array(
                               'name'          => __('What We Do'),
                               'singular_name' => __('What We Do'),

                           ),
                           'public'      => true,
                           'has_archive' => true,
                           'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail'),
                           'capability_type' => 'post',
                           'capabilities' => array(
                           'create_posts' => 'do_not_allow',
    ),
                           'map_meta_cap' => true, 


                       )
    );
}
add_action('init', 'whatwedo_custom_post_type');
```

Currently, I have the post title hardcoded within my `frontpage.php` template  like so:

```
<h1 class="ft-center">WHAT WE DO</h1>
```

I need to display the post title dynamically instead, meaning - whenever I change the custom post title in admin, I want to display the changed title on front-end. Currently, when I try to display the custom post title (out of the loop) with

```
<?php echo get_the_title( ); ?>
```

it displays the page title, instead of post title. What should I do to display the custom post title instead?

Comment: When you call get_the_title() outside of the loop it defaults to the current page. Your best bet is to use WP_Query to get the post you wish to display on the `frontpage.php` (You can use the post ID to do this) and use get_the_title() inside of the loop. Here is a answer on how to use WP_Query how I have mentioned. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/20037/wp-query-by-just-the-id?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa#answer-20038

Comment: Glad I could help :)